# antlr4 parentheses collide with double quote for string rules

Tags: antlr

I have defined a String like this:
`STRING_TOKEN: '"'[A-Za-z0-9]+'"';`
When i use a rule such : 
    `LENGTH_TOKEN '( 'function' )'                                               #lengthScalarOperator`

e.g: length("skip")

where function is a string, i got this error: mismatched input '("' expecting '('

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is, that it's looking for a ( token, but it finds a (" token, as you have not specified a token as "(". Try to move the two ' in `LENGTH_TOKEN` so it becomes `LENGTH_TOKEN '(' function ')'` instead.